# Treat singular and plural of a word as one

Tags: javascript, word-count

I am creating a web based word frequency counter using JavaScript. Is there any way so as to treat plural and singular as same.

**Example: love and loves are treated as one when showing frequency**

Any method using something other than JavaScript is also welcome!

Comment: What should be the logic behind `wolf` and `wolves`?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: what about octopus and octopi ...i don't think you can do this just an algorithm you'll probably need some kind of dictionary api

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually it is an assignment and I was wondering if it is even possible!

Comment: it is possible - since it is for an assignment, we won't just complete it for you.

Comment: also, you probably won't be able to tell the plural form of a noun and a third person singular verb apart where the verb form of the noun is the same as the noun itself (e.g.: try - tries).

Comment: The term you're looking for is "stemming". Also, look into wordnet.

Answer (score 0):

Define a [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246980/how-to-create-a-simple-map-using-javascript-jquery) with all the synonyms for each word, and search on that map before counting a word.

This might help you: [Porters Stemming Algorithm Javascript, How to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133389/porters-stemming-algorithm-javascript-how-to)

Comment: True. I've replaced it.